# Address of upcast object

Tags: c++

Suppose `B` is a base class of `D` (maybe virtual, maybe multiple inheritance, need not be a direct base class).

Let `obj` be an object of type `D` (not of a subclass of `D` -- exactly `D`).

Let

```
D * d = std::addressof(obj);
B * b = d;
```

Can we safely assume that

```
(char*) d <= (char*) b && (char*) b < (char*) d + sizeof(D)
```

?

Background: This is to become a step in a routine determining whether some object has been created by placement `new` in a particular `aligned_storage`. I need to be sure that, if yes, all pointers to base objects of this object point to some address within the `aligned_storage`.

Comment: the problem is `multiple inheritance` (C inherits both A and B for example). it seems that you need to use `dynamic_cast` and not the direct cast you used. If you have classes which inherits without `multiple inheritence`, you will have always the same address.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant `dynamic_cast` is not needed for upcasting, even in the presence of multiple inheritance and virtual inheritance.  That is, `b = d` does not necessarily mean `b` and `d` are the same physical address.

Comment: I _think_ the answer is yes. I realise it's not a proof and it's kind of tedious but you could write a humongous test suite with lots of combinations of `B` and `D` and `B2` and `D2` etc to pretty much find out.

Comment: When you say "Let `obj` be an object of type `D`" - does it have to be a most-derived object? Can it be a sub-object of another object? In the latter case - yes, it is possible for a subobject of a virtual base class to be physically located outside of its derived class' object. In a diamond-shaped hierarchy, it has to be, on at least one branch (there's just one virtual base instance, but two subobjects derived from it - they can't both contain it).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that your assumption is safe given D is the final type of the object. Otherwise it would be treacherous to use placement new in the first place.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <new>

struct B { int i; };
struct D : virtual B { int j; };

int
main()
{
    auto const storage = malloc(sizeof(D));
    D* d = new (storage) D();
    free(storage);
    return 0;
}
```

If `B` were located before `d` then the placement new would need to return a pointer adjusted based on the layout of `D` but "the standard allocation function void* operator new(std::size_t, void*) ... simply returns its second argument unchanged." (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) Likewise, the storage of `B` cannot be situated such that it extends beyond `(char*)d + sizeof(D)` because it would overrun the memory allocated.

Thanks for sharing an interesting question. Perhaps since asking the question you have already found a more satisfactory answer. I would be interested in reading a more concrete proof why the assumption holds or does not.